# compiling truecrypt on synology

Tags: linux, compilation, truecrypt

I'm trying to compile and install truecrypt on my synology box (DS212J) following this article but I am not getting any success.

http://systemsnotebook.blogspot.com/2011/05/truecrypt-7-on-synology.html

Starting in the first step when I try to run

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/local CFLAGS="-march=i686" CC=gcc
```

I get

```
Home> ./configure --prefix=/opt/local CFLAGS="-march=i686" CC=gcc
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/volume1/BACKUP/nasm-2.10':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I'm running on

Marvell Kirkwood mv6281 1.2Ghz ARM Processor (Marvell ARMADA 300)   16-bit@DDR2, 256MB of RAM

Based on

```
http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/What_kind_of_CPU_does_my_NAS_have
```

Comment: As per Christophe Vu-Brugier 's comment, he is correct. Those instructions are for a i686 atom powered NAS the 1511+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ./configure --prefix=/opt/local CFLAGS="-march=i686" CC=gcc
>
> I'm running on
> Marvell Kirkwood mv6281 1.2Ghz ARM Processor (Marvell ARMADA 300) 16-bit@DDR2, 256MB of RAM

You are compiling for the wrong architecture. Your NAS has an ARM processor and you build Truecrypt for x86.

If you are compiling on your NAS, then you should just invoke ./configure without specifying the target architecture:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/local CC=gcc
```

On the other hand, if you build truecrypt on your PC for your NAS, then you need to install a cross compiler and must pass the correct options to ./configure (i.e. "host" and "target").